# In pandas, how do I perform filtering on a DataframeGroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas

Given I have the following csv `data.csv`:

```
id,category,price,source_id
1,food,1.00,4
2,drink,1.00,4
3,food,5.00,10
4,food,6.00,10
5,other,2.00,7
6,other,1.00,4
```

I want to group the data by (price, source_id) and I am doing it with the following code

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['id', 'category', 'price', 'source_id'])
grouped = df.groupby(['price', 'source_id'])
valid_categories = ['food', 'drink']
for price_source, group in grouped:
    if group.category.size < 2:
        continue

    categories = group.category.tolist()
    if 'other' in categories and len(set(categories).intersection(valid_categories)) > 0:
        pass
        """
        Valid data in this case is:

        1,food,1.00,4
        2,drink,1.00,4
        6,other,1.00,4

        I will need all of the above data including the id for other purposes
        """
```

Is there an alternate way to perform the above filtering in pandas before the for loop and if it's possible, will it be any faster than the above?

The criteria for filtering is:

- size of the group is greater than 1
- the group by data should contain category `other` and at least one of either `food` or `drink`

Answer (score 0):

You could directly apply a custom filter to the GroupBy object, something like

```
crit = lambda x: all((x.size > 1, 
                      'other' in x.category.values, 
                      set(x.category) & {'food', 'drink'}))

df.groupby(['price', 'source_id']).filter(crit)
```

**Outputs**

```
  category  id  price  source_id
0     food   1    1.0          4
1    drink   2    1.0          4
5    other   6    1.0          4
```